# Some unwanted random values appending in script tag

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I have removed some malware from a website but my googleads is not approved. I asked them they said there is an issue with javascript tag.

I want to know is that correct or not.

Our default script tag like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

In my site, it's like this,

```
<script type="97cff6b6a96fb71b51b40788-text/javascript">
```

That random value is appending in the front and it's dynamically changing whenever site refreshed. Can you please tell what is the difference between these two script tag values? Is this causing of a googleads block?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I wanted to share what fixed it for us.

It turns out that the random prefix does not come from Magento, but rather is part of Cloudflare's Rocket Loader service.

To solve the problem, the workaround was to add **data-cfasync="false"** to the script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

needs to be

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: It works, I am adding JS in admin area, but on live server script changing like type="dsafdsafdsa-text/javascipt" after adding cfasync tag it stoped to converting.
Can you let me know in backend have any option to stop this because in local it not converting but on live server it converting.

Answer (score 0):

Magento never adds this type of string in java script tag. There might be some malicious code. You need to debug and check, from where it's being happened.

Have you implemented SUPEE-11086 patch? if not then don't wait and just implement it.

https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-11086

Comment: Yes, I have added all the patches upto date

Answer (score 0):

Must have 50 reputation to comment...
I would like to add that this feature of CloudFlare can be disabled altogether:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/speed/optimization/content/rocket-loader/enable/